# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date Error on using Clock.systemUTC()

Tags: java, date

I am getting an parse error while parsing a date

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-06-17T05:49:41.174Z"
> Unparseable date: "2021-06-17T05:49:41.174Z"

my code looks like this

```
private static String generateAndValidate(int count) {
        Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC(); 
        String clockTime=clock.instant().toString();
        String result=clockTime;
        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            output.parse(clockTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("process date parse error. Going for retry.");
            
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Also tried hard coding the value here

```
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            output.parse("2021-06-17T05:49:41.174Z");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("process date parse error. Going for retry.");
            
        }
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Since you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, don’t also mix in the old and troublesome `SImpleDateFormat` class. `Clock` is part of java.time. Also, what is the bigger goal you are trying to obtain? We can probably help you find a better way.

Comment: Why do you still use `SimpleDateFormat`? It has been obsolete since a long time. Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead. See deHaar's answer.

Comment: I have hesitatingly listed *Parse Date String in Java [duplicate]* as an original question. Beware that the accepted answer there is incorrect. [The other answer, by achAmháin,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52480421/5772882) is good.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: The reason for the failing of your code is in the answer given by @GS3!**

My answer provides alternatives that are generally considered mroe up-to-date:

I would not recommend to use a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` here because you are involving a very old and practically outdated API while you are receiving the time by the modern API utilizing a `java.time.Clock`.

A good move would be to use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`s for parsing, but I think you could even skip the clock and use `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)`.

However, this code definitely parses the `String` produced by your first lines:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your first two lines
    Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();
    String clockTime = clock.instant().toString();
    // a hint to the problem
    System.out.println(clockTime + " <--- 6 fractions of second");
    // how to parse a String like that in plain java.time
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(clockTime);
    System.out.println(odt.format(
                            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
                            )
    );
}
```

The output of that will look like the following (obviously having different values):

```
2021-06-17T06:34:55.490370Z <--- 6 fractions of second
2021-06-17T06:34:55.49037Z
```

The output that uses a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is just one option, you can still define your own pattern using a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(yourPatternString)`, a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` in order to handle optional parts or one of the other built-in formatters.

If you just want to get the current moment and store it in a some datetime class, you can use the `now()` method the datetime classes in `java.time` have:

```java
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

looks suitable here, but there's a `ZonedDateTime`, too.

Just have a look at `java.time`...

Answer (score 1):

In SimpleDateFormat, `Z` represents a [restricted subset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) of the RFC-822 time zone syntax. [Instant::toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) provides a timestamp in the ISO-8601 format. You can fix this by using X instead of Z.

```
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: This definitely solves the particular problem here, so +1, but OP should stop using a `SimpleDateFormat`.